# Sort dataframe per column reassigning indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given this dataframe:

```
print(df)

        0          1     2
0   354.7      April   4.0
1    55.4     August   8.0
2   176.5   December  12.0
3    95.5   February   2.0
4    85.6    January   1.0
5     152       July   7.0
6   238.7       June   6.0
7   104.8      March   3.0
8   283.5        May   5.0
9   278.8   November  11.0
10  249.6    October  10.0
11  212.7  September   9.0
```

If I do order by column 2 using `df.sort_values('2')`, I get:

```
        0          1     2
4    85.6    January   1.0
3    95.5   February   2.0
7   104.8      March   3.0
0   354.7      April   4.0
8   283.5        May   5.0
6   238.7       June   6.0
5   152.0       July   7.0
1    55.4     August   8.0
11  212.7  September   9.0
10  249.6    October  10.0
9   278.8   November  11.0
2   176.5   December  12.0
```

Is there a smart way to re-define the index column (from 0 to 11) preserving the new order I got?

Comment: [reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

Comment: df.reset_index()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reset_index`:

```
df.sort_values('2').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Also (this will replace the original dataframe)

```
df[:] = df.sort_values('2').values
```